# Compute cdf and pdf given f(x)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having trouble computing the cdf and pdf of the problem below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What have you done so far? Anyway, the hint goes like follows:
(a) $$F_M(m) = \mathbb{P}[\{M\leq m\}]=\mathbb{P}[\{\mathrm{max}(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)\leq m\}]=\mathbb{P}[\{X_1\leq m,X_2 \leq m,\dots,X_n \leq m \}]=\int_{x_1=0}^m \int_{x_2=0}^m \dots \int_{x_n=0}^m f_{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n) \space \mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\dots \mathrm{d}x_n$$ and just split it by independence as given, you should get the desired answer. PDF is just the differentiation of CDF.
(b) For this one try using the same trick as in the first one but in a slightly different manner.

Comment: Re (a), while the subscript $M$ in $F_M$ has a precise meaning, the various subscripts appended to the three occurrences of the symbol $P$ have none--actually they might even be misleading. Re (b), I am curious to know whether this "solution" helped the OP at all.